# Validate content in EditText

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I have  16 `EditText`s and I want to validate each one. For example, if the edittext is null or blank (""), I want to fill it with a 0 when a button is pressed.
This is my code:

```
package com.selmes;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 EditText txt1 ;
 EditText txt2;
 EditText txt3 ;
    EditText txt4 ;
    EditText txt5 ;
    EditText txt6;
    EditText txt7;
    EditText txt8;
    EditText txt9;
    TextView tv ;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   Button limpiar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.limpiar);
  limpiar.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
     EditText txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
 EditText txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
 EditText txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    EditText txt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    EditText txt5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt5);
    EditText txt6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt6);
    EditText txt7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt7);
    EditText txt8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt8);
    EditText txt9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt9);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            txt1.setText("0");
        txt2.setText("0");
        txt3.setText("0");
        txt4.setText("0");
        txt5.setText("0");
        txt6.setText("0");
        txt7.setText("0");
        txt8.setText("0");
        txt9.setText("0");
        tv.setText("");
    }
});
            /** boton de calcular resultado con su procedimientos */
Button calcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
calcular.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     EditText txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
     EditText txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
     EditText txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        EditText txt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
        EditText txt5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt5);
        EditText txt6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt6);
        EditText txt7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt7);
        EditText txt8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt8);
        EditText txt9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt9);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9;
    if (txt1.getText().equals("")) txt1.setText(0);
        n1=Integer.parseInt( txt1.getText().toString());
n2=Integer.parseInt( txt2.getText().toString());
n3=Integer.parseInt( txt3.getText().toString());
n4=Integer.parseInt( txt4.getText().toString());
n5=Integer.parseInt( txt5.getText().toString());
n6=Integer.parseInt( txt6.getText().toString());
n7=Integer.parseInt( txt7.getText().toString());
n8=Integer.parseInt( txt8.getText().toString());
n9=Integer.parseInt( txt9.getText().toString());
int res=  (n1 * n5 * n9) + (n4 * n8 * n3) + (n7 * n2 * n6) - (n7 * n5 * n3) - (n8 * n6 * n1) - (n9 * n4 * n2);
tv.setText("La determinante es:" + res);
    }
            });
// pasar al siguiente actividad
    Button a4x4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4x4);
    a4x4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intento = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ec4x4.class);
        startActivity(intento);
                }
    });
    }
  }
```

Are there any bugs in this code? How can I fix them?

Comment: do you want to check this while user is typing or after the user clicked some button?

Comment: after clicked the " calc " button

Answer (score 1):

Why did you redeclare your TextViews in the Listener? They are already referenced in your onCreate method.

J.

Comment: because , when i declare in Oncreate Method , mark mistake and app doesn't run well how can i declare my controls or where i shoud to do? i'm newbie in android

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

Create and array of EditText

```
 List<EditText> txtList = new ArrayList<EditText>;
```

Your `onCreate` will look like this:

```
`txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt3));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt5));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt6));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt7));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt8));
txtList.add((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt9));`
```

Create api `validateAndSetToZero`

```
void validateAndSetToZero(List<EditText> editTextList) {
  for(EditText et : editTextList)
    if(et.getText().toString().equals(""))
      et.setText("0");
}
```

Your onClick of button should look like:

```
calcular.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    validateAndSetToZero(txtList);
    // Below will be your other logic
}
```

Comment: ok, i did the example that u give me, but doesn't work , since i learned to debug , never validate with equals method , i tried ´et.getText().equals("") and et.getText().equals(null)   ´ but never work any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is you should extend the EditText in your own and override the getText() method.
One more comment about your code, it is so ... messy.
firstly, define your variable before call in in any function.
Then, initialize them in onCreate method.
As i saw, you should define override onClick method for buttons by implement View.OnClickListener in your MainActivity class.